# How to get rid of Error Code 1242

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the lines of code in My SQL Workbench, but I am receiving the error:  Error Code: 1242.  Subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
 SELECT Fname, Lname, Dnum, Pno 
 FROM EMPLOYEE e, PROJECT p, WORKS_ON w 
 WHERE p.Dnum = (SELECT Dno FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE e.Ssn = w.Essn AND w.Pno = p.Pnumber)
```

I am trying to display a table of employees that are working on a project that is not sponsored by their department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dnum, Pno 
FROM EMPLOYEE e, PROJECT p, WORKS_ON w 
WHERE p.Dnum in (SELECT Dno FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE e.Ssn = w.Essn AND w.Pno = 
p.Pnumber);
```

use `in` clause instad `=`

Comment: It worked!!  What correction did you make that it worked?  Also, do you have to use semicolons at the end of a statement?

Answer (score 0):

Optimized  query:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Dnum, Pno 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN  WORKS_ON  w ON e.Ssn = w.Essn
INNER JOIN  PROJECT  p  ON  w.Pno = p.Pnumber AND p.Dnum = e.Dno
```

Comment: May return duplicate rows. (Depending on table data.)